# How do I dynamically set content in a static html file in Gatsby.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I want to inject a url (`process.env.loginProviderUrl`) in a static page for an external authentication provider which I've placed in the `static` folder which Gatsby automatically copies over to the `public` folder when building.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="salesforce-community" content="{process.env.loginProviderUrl}" />
    <script
      src="{process.env.loginProviderUrl}/servlet/servlet.loginwidgetcontroller?type=javascript_widget"
      async="true"
      defer="true"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

But because it's in the static folder, it only gets copied over and the `process.env.loginProviderUrl` will never get replaced. How do I dynamically generate an html file in Gatsby which then gets copied to the static folder?

Comment: Why you not using react helmet?

Answer (score 0):

If you move your file to a separate folder that isn't processed by Gatsby you can instead set up a separate webpack configuration that will package files from that folder and provide them with ENV vars.

Alternately you could create a postbuild routine that uses simpler shell commands to find and replace instances of `process.env.loginProviderUrl` with the value from the local environment (e.g. [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)).

This said, it may simply be easier to find another way to include this file in your Gatsby app.